# What is the WPF XAML syntax to set a subproperty on a ViewModel exposed by the code-behind?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have user control that has a property named "LoginViewModel". It holds an instance of the viewmodel that the control is bound to.

The LoginViewModel has a property named "UserName" (the class implements INotifyPropertyChanged).

When I use the user control on another page, I want to be able to set some of the properties on the LoginViewModel property through the XAML. I can't quite seem to come up with the correct syntax for it. I could expose these directly in the code-behind and set them like this:

```
<rcs:LoginComponent x:Name="Login" UserName="Test"></rcs:LoginComponent>
```

But then I basically have to duplicate all of the properties from my ViewModel, which is silly.

I've tried variations of this:

```
<rcs:LoginComponent x:Name="Login">
   <rcs:LoginViewModel UserName="Test"></rcs:LoginViewModel>
</rcs:LoginComponent>
```

But then the control doesn't render (no errors, though). I just end up with a control that displays the namespace to the view model (Ex. MyApp.Components.LoginViewModel").

What's the syntax for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add `LoginViewModel` within `DataContext` tags of your UserControl like this:

```
<rcs:LoginComponent x:Name="Login">
   <rcs:LoginComponent.DataContext>
      <rcs:LoginViewModel UserName="Test"/>
   </rcs:LoginComponent.DataContext>
</rcs:LoginComponent>
```

Comment: Excellent. I never would have come up with that.